# Which sentry version dose support web vitals monitoring?

Tags: sentry, core-web-vitals

I found that [sentry is supporting monitoring web vitals metrics](https://docs.sentry.io/product/performance/web-vitals/), but I don't see any document which mentions about version supported.

I'm using `self-hosted` version 9.0, I don't know which version should be upgraded for supporting this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Sentry 21 supports Web Vitals.